# .net C# API GW triggered AWS Lambda returns "Connection refused" when sending to AWS SQS

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

My trivial .net C# AWS Lambda function, which is triggered by a HTTP GET to API GW runs but returns "Connection refused" when sending to AWS SQS

```
responseSendMsg = await sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(sendMessageRequest);
```

It seems the call to SQS is the issue.

Here is the full code, it is 90% generated by Visual Studio 2019, [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/welcome.html), new AWS project template "AWS Serverless Application (.NET Core - C#)", I have only:

1. Updated the lambda function handler method signature to be async
   with a Task, I followed the pattern documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html#csharp-handler-async

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> Get(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
```

2. Added in the code to write to SQS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents;
using Amazon.SQS;
using TEST.SQS;
using Amazon.SQS.Model;

[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace TestAsyncFromLambda
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public Functions()
        {
        }

        public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> Get(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Get Request\n");

            // Call a local async method to prove that works, leaving SQS out of the situation for the moment
            await Method1();


            // Create the Amazon SQS client
            var clientConfig = new AmazonSQSConfig
            {
                ServiceURL = SQSConstants.AWS_SERVICE_URL,
            };
            var sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(clientConfig);

            // Create and initialize a SendMessageRequest instance
            SendMessageRequest sendMessageRequest = new SendMessageRequest();
            sendMessageRequest.QueueUrl = SQSConstants.MyQueueUrl;
            sendMessageRequest.MessageBody = "this is a test message";

            Console.WriteLine($"About to send message to queue: {sendMessageRequest.QueueUrl}");

            // Send the SQS message using "await"
            SendMessageResponse responseSendMsg = null;
            try
            {
                responseSendMsg =
                await sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(sendMessageRequest);
                //responseSendMsg =
                //sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(sendMessageRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); ;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw e;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("SendMessage() complete");

            var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Body = "Hello AWS Serverless",
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "text/plain" } }
            };

            return response;
        }

        public static async Task Method1()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int iterations = 3;
                for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Method 1, i=" + i + " of " + iterations);
                    // Do something
                    Task.Delay(100).Wait();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this is a simplified example, I plan to do a lot of SQS processing in the function and expect that the use of async could be beneficial.

The cloud watch logs show the function has been triggered, gets as far as the send to SQS call, then throws an exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused
```

```
2021-06-24T16:13:54.751+10:00   START RequestId: MyID-91a3-f1e61c3c3f7a Version: $LATEST
2021-06-24T16:13:55.240+10:00   Get Request
2021-06-24T16:13:55.261+10:00   Method 1, i=1 of 3
2021-06-24T16:13:55.380+10:00   Method 1, i=2 of 3
2021-06-24T16:13:55.481+10:00   Method 1, i=3 of 3
2021-06-24T16:13:56.160+10:00   About to send message to queue: https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/MyID/MyQueue.fifo
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
2021-06-24T16:14:32.503+10:00   at TestAsyncFromLambda.Functions.Get(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in
```

I believe everything I am using is the latest version:
[image]

I also tried a few other permutations of C# async await syntax with the same result.

```
responseSendMsg = sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(sendMessageRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); ;
```

There is no VPC involved for the API GW, Lambda or SQS, everything is in the same AWS account, just a basic simple setup.

I also did a test where I changed the queue URL in SQS that the Lambda is sending to into an invalid queue name that does not exist, and I got identical behaviour, so this implies that possibly the SQS send request never even gets to AWS.

For the AWS .net SDK for SQS, there is no choice between sync and async methods for working with SQS, there is ONLY async: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/latest/developer-guide/SendMessage.html.

The Lambda function is attached to a role with these permissions, which I think should be sufficient:
[image]
I have even added the "AdministratorAccess" role, so I assume as long as the Lambda and SQS are on the same AWS account, the Lambda will have access to send to SQS.

The file aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json has:

```
{
    "Information" : [
        "This file provides default values for the deployment wizard inside Visual Studio and the AWS Lambda commands added to the .NET Core CLI.",
        "To learn more about the Lambda commands with the .NET Core CLI execute the following command at the command line in the project root directory.",
        "dotnet lambda help",
        "All the command line options for the Lambda command can be specified in this file."
    ],
    "profile"     : "myProfile",
    "region"      : "ap-southeast-2",
    "configuration" : "Release",
    "framework"     : "netcoreapp3.1",
    "s3-prefix"     : "TestAsyncFromLambda/",
    "template"      : "serverless.template",
    "template-parameters" : "",
    "s3-bucket"           : "awsserverless2stack-bucket-myID",
    "stack-name"          : "TestAsyncFromLambda"
}
```

The file serverless.template is:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application by matt.",
  "Resources": {
    "Get": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "TestAsyncFromLambda::TestAsyncFromLambda.Functions::Get",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 187,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
          "AmazonSQSFullAccess",
          "AdministratorAccess"
        ],
        "Events": {
          "RootGet": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "GET"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried both with a manually created queue via AWS Console Web UI and via Cloud Formation script, example taken from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/create-queue-cloudformation.html):

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "MyQueue": {
      "Properties": {
        "QueueName": "MyQueue.fifo",
        "FifoQueue": true,
        "ContentBasedDeduplication": true
      },
      "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue"
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "QueueName": {
      "Description": "The name of the queue",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "MyQueue",
          "QueueName"
        ]
      }
    },
    "QueueURL": {
      "Description": "The URL of the queue",
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "MyQueue"
      }
    },
    "QueueARN": {
      "Description": "The ARN of the queue",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "MyQueue",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I increased the lambda timeout to a long custom value to:

1. differentiate timeouts at that duration from other timeouts
2. give more time for SQS send to retry and/or timeout

I increased the timeout by changing serverless.template with:

```
"Timeout": 187,
```

Before increasing the timeout, when it was the default 30 seconds, I got not exception in the cloud watch logs, just as Lambda timeout.

Comment: Is your Lambda running in a VPC?

Comment: No, the lambda is not running in a vpc.

Comment: I am disapointed not to get a solution yet. I am going to try calling other code/libraries using await from the same lambda and see if they work. Any other ideas that I can try or info I can provide to get an answer here?

Comment: If instead of awaiting, you `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`? That should force it to run synchronously.

Comment: .GetAwaiter().GetResult(); produced identical result.

Comment: I don't believe the issue is with the `await`. I run `async` C# Lambda handlers all the time. IME well over 90% of timeouts like this are networking related, which is why I asked about the VPC. To get more help I suggest showing all the information you can about the configuration of the Lambda function.

Comment: Yes, I am starting to think await has nothing to do with it too. I will put up some screen shots of the Lambda config. Can you think of anything in particular I should share?

Comment: Is this url `https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/MyID/MyQueue.fifo` correct endpoint for SQS ?

Comment: What values you have in `SQSConstants.AWS_SERVICE_URL`  and `SQSConstants.MyQueueUrl` ?

Comment: @shahkalpeshp, the queue URL in my code/config was correct, but it is not that exact string, when posting here I removed part of the URL which I think might represent my AWS account ID for security reasons. Not sure if that was a good idea or not.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, thanks, you are correct!! SQSConstants.AWS_SERVICE_URL was set to an incorrect value, it was actually "http://localhost:4566" because I had previously been testing locally with localstack on port 4566. Please post this as an answer, so I can accept and put this embarrassing oversight behind me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, looks like the URL values being used for AWS Service URL and Queue URL are not correct. That's why the connection was failing while sending the messages.

So you need to make sure that `SQSConstants.AWS_SERVICE_URL` and `SQSConstants.MyQueueUrl` has correct values.

Comment: SQSConstants.AWS_SERVICE_URL was set to an incorrect value, it was actually "localhost:4566" because I had previously been testing locally with localstack on port 4566.